# Does chanting Mahishasura Mardini stotram bestow occult powers?

Tags: devi, stotra

Are there occult powers attributed to chanting the holy Mahishasura Mardini stotram?

The reason behind asking this is -
1.  some mantras/shlokas are chanted for invoking the specific deity for general well-being.
2. And there are some that have more potency - giving much higher perception to one who chants.
Does Mahishasura Mardini stotram come under the second category?

Answer (score 5):

We can't say for sure if reading this particular stotram gives the reader occult powers (i think you meant siddhis by that).

What one achieves upon reciting a stotram/kavacham is usually found in the phalasruti given at its end . In this case the author simply does not mention anything at all.

The last stanza of [the stotram](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/devi_durga-mahishasura_mardini_stotra.php) says only this:

> अयि मयि दीन दयालुतया कृपयैव त्वया भवितव्यमुमे अयि जगतो जननी कृपयासि
>   यथासि तथानुमितासिरते । यदुचितमत्र भवत्युररीकुरुतादुरुतापमपाकुरुते जय
>   जय हे महिषासुरमर्दिनि रम्यकपर्दिनि शैलसुते ॥ २१ ॥
>
> Ayi Mayi Diina Dayaalu-Tayaa Krpaya-Iva Tvayaa Bhavitavyam-Ume Ayi
>   Jagato Jananii Krpayaasi Yathaasi Tathanu-mita-Asira-Te |
>   Yad-Ucitam-Atra Bhavatyurarii-Kurutaa-Duru-Taapam-Apaakurute Jaya Jaya
>   He Mahissaasura-Mardini Ramya-Kapardini Shaila-Sute || 21 ||
>
> Meaning:
>   21.1: (Salutations to the Divine Mother) You Must Bestow Your Grace on Me, O Mother Uma, Who is Compassionate to the Miserable.
>   21.2: O Mother of the Universe; Just as Your Grace is Showered (on the Devotees), In the Same Manner are Your Arrows Scattered (on the
>   Enemies).
>   21.3 Please do Whatever is Appropriate at this time, O Worshipful Mother, to Remove My Sorrows and Afflictions which has become
>   Difficult for me to bear.
>   21.4: Victory to You, the Destroyer of the Demon Mahishasura, Who has Beautiful Locks of Hair and Who is the Daughter of the Mountain.

To understand what i am saying you can see Sri Adi Shankara's [Lalita Pancha Ratnam Stotram](http://stotrarathna.blogspot.in/2009/07/adhi-shankaras-lalitha-pancha-rathnam.html). Here, the phalasruti says:

> Ya sloka panchakam idham, Lalithambikya, Soubhagyuam, sulalitham
>   patathi prabhathe, Thasmai dadathi lalitha jadithi prasanna, Vidhyaam
>   sriyam vimala soukha manantha keerthim.
>
> **He who reads these five stanzas, In the morning** , extolling the mother
>   Lalitha,. Who is easy to please
>   **Would get luck, knowledge riches, endless fame By the grace of Goddess Lalitha.**

So, we know for sure what are achieved by reading this particular stotram and its clearly mentioned by the author himself.

[Here is another stotram](http://manotha.blogspot.in/2012/12/sri-lalita-panca-vimshati-nama-stotram.html) dedicated to Sri Lalita Mahatripurasundari called Sri Lalita Pancha Vimsati Nama Stotram (Pancha Vimasati is 25). This stotram is from the Brahmanda Purana. Its being told by Sri Hayagriva to Agastya Muni. Here, author clearly mentions that upon reading this stotram siddhis or super natural powers are obtained.

> स्तुवन्ति ये महाभागां ललितां परमेश्वरीम् | ते प्राप्नुवन्ति
>   सौभाग्यमष्टौ सिद्धीर्महद्यश: |6|
>
> stuvanti ye mahAbhAgAM lalitAM parameshvarIm |
>   **te prApnuvanti saubhAgyam-aShTau siddhIr-mahadyashaH ||**
>
> **One who recites these twenty-five names shall attain eight great
>   spiritual-accomplishments, prosperity and fame.**

So, IMO,  the answer to your question will be " we can't say for sure since the author himself has not mentioned any thing of that sort."

Comment: Do we get specifically these power only and only as stated in PhalaShruti? Or is it that PhalaShruti gives us examples of some powers which a particular hymn gives us and we can get more different kinds of siddhis?

Comment: @AnuragSingh We can probably get so its possible but we can't say with conviction. For example if i answer here saying **Yes** then people will ask **how do u know that?** To which i can't provide any definitive answer.